# Installing PHP APC on Windows/Apache

Tags: php, apache, apc

i need help installing and configuring PHP APC i have downloaded from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ in my PHP info, i see

```
Compiler       MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008) 
Architecture   x86
```

so i downloaded [php_apc-5.3-nts-svn20100226-vc9-x86.zip](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-5.3-nts-svn20100226-vc9-x86.zip). then to install, i tried adding

```
[PHP_APC]
extension=php_apc.dll
```

to `php.ini`. restarting Apache fails. trying to execute `php` in cmd results in an error saying `php5.dll is missing`. but i doubt so. removing the 2 lines from `php.ini` fixes the error. how can i install apc then?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: This is a very old answer. Since then I've used APC well with php5.4 and since the upgrade to php5.5 which removed APC, moved to memcached.

On Windows, seems php5.3 cannot work with APC. I simply use php5.2.5 instead as it's not a production machine anyway.

Comment: That is not true. I'm using APC with PHP 5.4 on Windows. See this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/21609013/2219831

Comment: This is a very old answer. Since then I've used APC well with php5.4 and since the upgrade to php5.5 which removed APC, moved to memcached.

Answer (score 1):

for the record :

> Which version do I choose?
>
> If you are using PHP with Apache1 or Apache2 from apache.org, you need to use the VC6 versions of PHP
>
> If you are using PHP with IIS, you should use the VC9 versions of PHP.
>
> VC6 Versions are compiled with the legacy Visual Studio 6 compiler
>
> VC9 Versions are compiled with the Visual Studio 2008 compiler and have improvements in performance and stability. The VC9 versions require you to have the Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x86) or the Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x64) installed
>
> Do NOT use VC9 version with apache.org binaries

**Short story** use vc6 for apache and vc9 for windows

Personally i use PHP `5.2.6` and `php_apc_3014_php521.dll`. It works in production.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I used this copy of PHP APC: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-3.1-svn20101116-5.3-vc6-x86.zip and it worked to put 3.1.7-dev in place on XAMPP 1.7.7 with PHP 5.3.8