# php installation error

Tags: php, apc

I have installed 'WampServer2.1e-x32' stack with addon version of php 5.2.11 . I downloaded apc3.0.19.dll and placed under the directory and required information in php.ini. To make it work.

Restarted wamp server and navigated to phpmyadmin and here are some error which I had never seen uptil now :(.

```
Notice: Unknown: 1. h->opened_path=[null] h->filename=[C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/index.php] in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: 2. h->opened_path=[C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\index.php] h->filename=[C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/index.php] in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: apc_cache_make_file_entry: entry->data.file.filename is [C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\index.php] in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Inserting [C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\index.php] in Unknown on line 0

Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: 1. h->opened_path=[C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\common.inc.php] h->filename=[./libraries/common.inc.php] in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\index.php on line 35

Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: 2. h->opened_path=[C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\common.inc.php] h->filename=[./libraries/common.inc.php] in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\index.php on line 35

Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: apc_cache_make_file_entry: entry->data.file.filename is [C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\common.inc.php] in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\index.php on line 35

Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: Inserting [C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\common.inc.php] in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\index.php on line 35

Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: 1. h->opened_path=[C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\Error_Handler.class.php] h->filename=[./libraries/Error_Handler.class.php] in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\common.inc.php on line 53

Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: Stat failed ./libraries/Error_Handler.class.php - bailing (C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/index.php) (1310476968) in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\common.inc.php on line 53

Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: 1. h->opened_path=[C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\Error.class.php] h->filename=[./libraries/Error.class.php] in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\Error_Handler.class.php on line 13

Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: Stat failed ./libraries/Error.class.php - bailing (C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/index.php) (1310476968) in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\Error_Handler.class.php on line 13

Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: 1. h->opened_path=[C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\Message.class.php] h->filename=[./libraries/Message.class.php] in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\Error.class.php on line 13

Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: Stat failed ./libraries/Message.class.php - bailing (C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/index.php) (1310476968) in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\Error.class.php on line 13
```

I had uninstalled it and re-installed it but still I receive this error !!. I wanted to run php 5.2.11 and APC and I have no idea why phpmyadmin got impacted !!!

I tried with different version for APC [php_apc-3.1.5-5.2-vc6-x86] and finally got the correct one which seems working in PHP [php_apc_3_0_19.dll] and it just directly impacted my phpmyadmin ...

I will again uninstall,delete all the wamp related files and start fresh......but my knowledge in APC is very limited...I may be thinking totally is different direction...

any help to resolve following problem is highly appreciated...

Comment: Try this version here. It is the only one that works without throwing tons of notices ;). https://mazicr.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/installing-apc-for-xampp-1-8-1-windows/

Answer (score 3):

A bit late for user269867, but I found a solution (APC 3.1.9 / 3.1.13) :

You can also follow this :

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59445

Where it is said :

"If compiling is not an option, roll back to stable: pecl install -f APC-3.1.6"

It is indeed a regression, but it worked fine for me :)

(I also responded that in [APC (Alternate PHP Cache) Throwing Lots of PHP Notices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518068/apc-alternate-php-cache-throwing-lots-of-php-notices))

Answer (score 2):

Looks like recent builds in windows.php.net are broken too.  I've tested:

1. php_apc-3.1.12-5.4-ts-vc9-x86
2. php_apc-3.1.13-5.4-ts-vc9-x86

both from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apc/, and both had this problem.

If you are stuck on this like I was, go to:
http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

And download php_apc-3.1.10-5.4-vc9-x86.zip.

Comment: Widows APC versions newer than `3.1.10` do not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If PHPMyAdmin is the only thing giving you problems, now is the time to switch. I find PHPMyAdmin slow, bulky, and way too many frames. I would recommend you switch to [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/), it's fast and easy to install.

Comment: I would recommend just using the mysql CLI. You don't need a PHP GUI to wrap a simple language you really should know well to write your  programs.

Comment: he was having problems with phpmyadmin, if he was comfortable with mysql cli, I doubt he would have asked

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the messages are surrounding phpMyAdmin's libraries directory, does that directory exist? If so, what are the permissions?

I see this error here which seems to be directly related to apc.:

```
Notice: require_once() [function.require-once]: apc_cache_make_file_entry: entry->data.file.filename is [C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\common.inc.php] in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\index.php on line 35
```

Also, these aren't errors, but notices, does myadmin function despite these?

Finally, I found this blog post, does this help? It seems like you can disable APC for phpmyadmin.

http://mattiasgeniar.be/2011/01/20/running-phpmyadmin-with-apc-cache-enabled-fatal-php-errors/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these errors are actually problems with PHPMyAdmin; they're part of the APC configuration settings. Apparently debugging was enabled. I think this can be resolved via https://stackoverflow.com/a/9032478/263877.