# Installing PHP APC in Windows

Tags: php, apache, apc

I can not find the correct version of php_apc.dll for my setup

```
System                  Windows Server 2008
Compiler                MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008) 
Architecture            x86 
PHP Extension Build     API20100525,TS,VC9 
PHP Version             5.4.4
Thread Safety           enabled 
Apache Version          Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 
Virtual Server          Yes 
Server API              Apache 2.4 Handler Apache Lounge
```

Sorry for my bad English and thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the right answer is the most recent production release compatible with your installation (although normally, upgrading PHP should not be a major headache). Since APC suppport is dropped from PHP v5.5 onwards, the most recent version of APC (3.1.3) will be the right one to go for. The PECL site [lists the builds](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC/3.1.13/windows) compatible with your current setup.

(NB upgrading to 5.5 is a bigger jump than previous minor number upgrades due to the change to Zend opcode+optimizer)

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use the *. Dll "5.4 Thread Safe (TS) x86", but opening any php page appear different errors such as: Notice: Unknown: 1. h->opened_path=[null] h->filename=[xxxx] in Unknown on line 0
Notice: Unknown: apc_cache_find [-1302308902] in Unknown on line 0
Notice: Unknown: 2. h->opened_path=[xxx] h->filename=[xxx] in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Try going back a version at time then - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665849/php-installation-error